# How to read price values from Fib Retracement lines?

Tags: pine-script

I want to draw Fib Retracement levels for some swing in price (from High to Low). Then I want to run some script and compare current price value with price of my Fib levels, but I don't know how to read them - if it's even possible.

I succeed doing this when I'm using Auto Fib Retracement tool, but problem is because levels are dynamic and they could change if price makes new swing (they are dynamic).

You can also point me on some code which will draw fixed Fib Levels where I want and then get price values for these levels if it's possible.

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `Auto Fib Retracement` indicator is open source. You can make the copy and modify it" - add `if barstate.ishistory` for zigzag calculations and futher RT updates will not affect on fib levels:

```
...
if barstate.ishistory // new line of code
    if not na(iH)
        dev = calc_dev(pLast, pH)
        [id, isHigh] = pivotFound(dev, true, iH, pH)
        if not na(id)
            if id != lineLast
                line.delete(lineLast)
            lineLast := id
            isHighLast := isHigh
            iPrev := iLast
            iLast := iH
            pLast := pH
    else
        if not na(iL)
            dev = calc_dev(pLast, pL)
            [id, isHigh] = pivotFound(dev, false, iL, pL)
            if not na(id)
                if id != lineLast
                    line.delete(lineLast)
                lineLast := id
                isHighLast := isHigh
                iPrev := iLast
                iLast := iL
                pLast := pL
...
```